# Provisioning profile becomes invalid everyday

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have recently renewed my developer certificate and I’m using Xcode 7. I’m using the same developer account in four different Macs. But ever since I renewed my certificate, the next day morning my all my apps pointing that certificate is crashing and when I log into my developer account I’m finding all my profiles invalid. This happens everyday. Things I’ve tried are

1. Deleted the App ID and recreated it (did not work)
2. Removed all old profiles from the Mac and Developer account (did not work)
3. Deleted my iOS Development Certificate and created again (did not work)

What I’m doing these past days is Edit the profile and choose my Certificate everyday.

Any help?

Comment: Are you seeing any certificates that are valid after yours become invalid?  I haven't see it with certificates, but I have seen Xcode invalidate provisioning profiles when developers use the "Fix" button when letting Xcode try to manage the certs / and profiles.

Comment: No certificates remained the same but provisioning profile expires everyday when "Fix" button is clicked, exactly as you said. why does this occurs? Why Xcode wants to fix issue when I have valid profile?

Comment: Basically, Xcode is trying to take over managing the provisioning profiles.  In order to prevent a conflict between the existing provisioning profile and the one Xcode is going to create, it invalidates any that are out there.  Having two provisioning profiles for the same app ID and certificate causes an ambiguous provisioning profile error in Xcode, because it then cannot tell which of the two profiles it should use to build the app.

Comment: How can I avoid this?

Comment: Basically, if you want to manage the provisioning profiles outside of Xcode, you should never use the "Fix" button.  On the machine where you generated the new cert signing request for the new certificate, you'll want to export the certificate, along with the private key from your Keychain to then import on all the other Macs you use for development.  Then recreate the provisioning profiles on the Apple developer portal, install them on the 4 Macs, and Xcode should not prompt you to "fix" anything.

Answer (score 0):

I delete the same AppID Development Profiles but keep one that managed by Xcode.Then I open the Xcode and enter the "Setting" > "Accounts" > Choose the developer account that I used > "View Detail" > Signing Identities:iOS development "Reset" > "DownLoadAll". then it is OK.
Remember:if you let Xcode manage your certificates,just make sure that "one AppID, one development Profiles".